# vim substitution expand to uppercase

Tags: vim

I insert the name of my file into its skeleton when i open it with this command into my ~/.vimrc file :

```
function! HPPFile()
    silent! 0r $HOME/.vim/templates/skeleton.hpp
    %s/FileName/\=expand("%:t:r")/g
    %s/FILENAME/\U\=expand("%:t:r")\E/g
endfunction
autocmd BufNewFile *.hpp call HPPFile()
```

the first expansion line works well `%s/FileName/\=expand("%:t:r")/g` : all instances of `FileName` get replaced by the file name

but the second expansion line doesn't works `%s/FILENAME/\U\=expand("%:t:r")\E/g` -> it seems i cannot use both the uppercase substitution and the expand action

I've tried some variations but without chance, how could i do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems once you're in evaluation mode you must use it for everything. Try

```
%s/FILENAME/\=toupper(expand("%:t:r"))/g
```

Comment: perfect ! thx :)

Comment: FWIW: `:help string-functions` and `:help toupper()`.

Answer (score 7):

From `:help sub-replace-\=`:

```
When the substitute string starts with "\=" the remainder is interpreted as an
expression.
```

You can use `:help substitute()` to uppercase your filename:

```
function! HPPFile()
    silent! 0r $HOME/.vim/templates/skeleton.hpp
    %s/FileName/\=expand("%:t:r")/g
    %s/FILENAME/\=substitute(expand("%:t:r"),'.*','\U&','')/g
endfunction
```

Comment: thank you :) i can use this solution if I have something more complicated to do than just uppercase !